# High Sierra - make mouse pointer follow focus

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, mouse, shortcut

Mac works great when I use keyboard shortcuts and Spotlight Search in a single-display environment to switch between windows and workspaces.

However, this is not the case in a multi-display setup, because the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> shortcuts that switch to left and right workspace operate based on which display my mouse pointer currently is. If I started on display 1, and then through keyboard shortcuts, moved focus to display 2, if I want to switch workspaces on display 2, I can't just hit <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, because doing so will actually switch the workspaces on display 1, where my mouse pointer still is. I have to actually move my hand to the mouse, move the mouse pointer to display 2, and then use the keyboard shortcuts to switch the workspaces.

Is there a way to either make all shortcuts operate based on where the focus is, instead of where the mouse pointer is, or else have macOS automatically move the mouse pointer to the display with the focused window when focus changes? There's no point in keyboard shortcuts that force me to use the mouse, anyway.

Comment: There's always the option to disable system prefs > mission control > 'displays have separate Spaces' [which I loathe, for many reasons, not least your issue.] Then both screens move as pairs.

Comment: Eh, I would still prefer for each screen to have its own spaces.  I purpose my monitors for particular uses, which normally means particular applications go to each display (for instance, screen 1 for e-mail and im apps, screen 2 for terminals and code editors, screen 3 for browsers, music apps, etc).  Can't really get that sandboxing/purposing without designating the workspaces to a screen.  I still haven't encountered any OS configuration that works better than my very basic X11+XMonad setup.

Comment: Then you're going to have to indicate to the computer which screen you mean... the cursor is that indication.

Comment: ^ Another strike against the Mac for usability.

Comment: I’m not really understanding how you think it might otherwise read your mind;)

Comment: Based on which window is in focus at the time, and which monitor that in-focus window is on.  Same way Windows and Linux know... The focus should be the indicator of which screen is active, regardless of whether a mouse-click or a keyboard shortcut brought the active window into focus. @Tetsujin